# Is it possible to connect an Angular CdkDropList to a CdkDragBoundary?

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk

I am currently using the angular CDK drag and drop feature and I want to move elements from a CdkDropList to a CdkDragBoundary, therefore I need to connect them. To explain this better, imagine a drag and drop list on the side of a div, I want the elements from the list to become free draggable elements in the div, however this seems to not work with cdkDropList and cdkDragBoundary and it does not work with two cdkDropLists either from what I've tested. Please if anyone has any idea how this can be handled let me know, even if it is a solution without drop lists or drop boundaries.

```
<div cdkDropList 
     #mapList="cdkDropList"  
     [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[labelsList]" 
     class="map-container">
   <div id="map"></div>
</div>
<div class="answers-container">
   <div class="answers-title"><span>Labels</span></div>
   <div cdkDropList 
        #labelsList="cdkDropList" 
        [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[mapList]" 
        class="answers-labels">
     <div cdkDrag 
          cdkDragBoundary=".map-container" 
          id="answer.id" class="answers-labels-box"  
          [ngStyle]="{'background-color':answer.color }"
          *ngFor="let answer of answers">
         <span cdkDragHandle class="grab"><i class="pi pi-times"></i></span>
         {{answer.text}}
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your issue, but to limit the cdkDrag within a list you would do:

```
  <div cdkDropList #mapList> 
     <div cdkDrag [cdkDragBoundary]="mapList">drag me</div>
  </div>
```